# Is this model valid?

Tags: probability, model, biostatistics

I would like to know whether this model is valid with respect to the calculation of the probability outcome.

I apologize for the length, but to determine its validity you will need to know the definition of the terms. Additional information is provided below in a separate section if needed.

$$ P_3 = P_1  P_2 $$

$P_3$ represents the probability of generating a specific conserved protein sequence needed for a living primitive proto-organism. There are two components: $P_1$ and $P_2$.

#### $P_1$ section

$P_1$ relates to the amount of information present in any one specific protein sequence of a given length. $P_1$ represents the probability of producing the specific protein sequence, corrected for the probability that more than one sequence can produce a living organism.

For this model I used 250 proteins, with an average size of 300 amino acids (AA). I also made this model simpler by stipulating that we only need 10 AAs, not all 20, making this a base 10 equation. I merged them (all one long sequence) because it is the information we are looking at, not the actual proteins.

$N_1 = 250$ amino acids per protein

$N_2 = 300$ proteins

$N_3 = N_1 N_2 = (250)(300) = 75,000 $

The probability of a specific sequence (for example) of 7 AAs from a pool of 10 possible is 1 chance in $10^7$ or $10^{-7}$, thus the probability of these 75000 AA occurring in one exact, specified sequence is the inverse of $10^{75000}$, or $1/10^{75000}$ or $10^{-75000}$.

$$P_1 = 1/10^{N_3} = 1/10^{75000} = 10^{-75000} $$

One debate related to this model is that it is possible that more than one sequence generates a living organism. $L_{max}$ is the correction factor for this, and represents the total number of past and present living organisms known.

$$ L_{max} = 10^{10} $$

The corrected equation then becomes:

$$P_1 = (1/10^{N_3})(L_{max}) = (1/10^{75000})(10^{10}) = (10^{-75000})(10^{10}) = 10^{-74990} $$

The probability $P_1$ of generating a specific conserved sequence of amino acids from a pool of 10 possible AAs is 1 chance in $10^{74990}$ or $10^{-74990}$.

#### $P_2$ section

$P_2$ represents the total number of protein-synthetic events possible. This represents how many chances we get to generate the protein sequence.

$$P_2=FTVD$$

In this model, peptide bond-formation events for protein synthesis are happening at a high frequency F, for the entire length of time T, using the volume of the earth V, at density of events D.

$P_2$ represents this total number of all possible events that can occur to generate proteins.

$F = 10^6$ events/sec

$T = 10^{18}$ seconds (age of the universe)

$V = 10^{39}$ µl (earth's volume in microliters)

$D = 10^6$ events/µl

$$P_2= FTVD = (10^6)(10^{18})(10^{39})(10^6) = 10^{69} $$

#### $P_3$ calculation

Thus the expanded equation is:

$$ P_3 = (10^{-(N_1N_2)})(L_{max})(FTVD) $$

$$ P_3 = (10^{-75000})(10^{10})((10^6)(10^{18})(10^{39})(10^6)) $$

$$ P_3 = (10^{-74990})(10^{69}) $$

$$ P_3 = 10^{-74921} $$

Therefore, the probability of generating a specific, conserved sequence of amino acids that represents the information present in a set of 250 proteins of 300 AAs long is 1 chance in $10^{74921}$.

## More reading

(skip if desired)
(Clarification and justification of terms and values)

The setting is abiogenesis: Darwin’s “warm little pond” if you will. We know that about 4 billion years ago there was no life, and then about 3 billion years ago, life began. Fairly quickly we see the appearance of cyanobacteria – fairly complex as bacteria go.

In 2006, Mulkidjanian and others published in the Proceedings of the National Academy of Science on the topic “The cyanobacterial genome core and the origin of photosynthesis”. This article references how many gene products were thought to be needed for a proto-cyanobacterial organism. It amounts to about 1000 proteins, with an average protein size of about 325 AA. However, the first primitive proto-organism was probably a lot smaller.

The formula provides the probability of producing the information required to generate a living organism by random chance and/or natural processes, based on expected specific information requirements. We know that there are highly conserved genes across all organisms - for example the protein sequences in the 16S rRNA protein, and that in the 23S rRNA protein. These are highly conserved and similar in bacteria and humans. These are just two examples of many.

It helps to understand cellular biological processes to understand the model – but I don’t think it’s required. Truly – I think the model is independent of a complex understanding of that. You do need to know that there are 20 amino acids that form the building blocks of proteins. Most people with a high-school education should be able to grasp this.

As a model, this is not intended to consider everything, just some important components that I think demonstrate the information requirements. This model just considers protein synthesis from amino acids. It's the simplest type of information required; one doesn't need a variety of combinations of three nucleotides, just a simple amino acid sequence. To be clear, I am not referring to a genome, or DNA, or RNA. This model is looking at just the information required to produce specific proteins of specific sequences. It does not consider the fact that modern processes require all three (RNA, DNA, and proteins). It does not consider an RNA-first hypothesis of abiogenesis. So, even though I use 16S and 23S rRNA proteins as examples above, this model only examines the information intrinsic in the protein sequence.

I am familiar with Claude Shannon’s work on information and some of his equations, but I really wanted to try and keep this simple.

Using only half of the AAs means that we decrease the information needed by a lot, some of which was likely not specific, conserved, and/or sequentially important. This component of the model accounts for any arguments for redundancy in the AA sequence. Thus, we determine that half of the 20 modern amino acids are not considered in this model, but the remaining half…their sequence is important and specific.

Since they are all important and their sequence is specific, I pooled them and consider them as one sequence. The information gain/loss at the intersection of protein sequences is simply ignored and sacrificed in order to simplify the model.

The minimum number of specifically sequenced amino acids is 250 x 300 = 75,000. These have to be in the right sequence for the organism to exist, grow, divide, procreate etc. While we know that there would be 250 separate proteins – it makes the model easier to calculate by just assuming one big long sequence and ignoring that.

However, more than one sequence may result in our proto-organism being viable. To account for this, the following model adjustment is used. The current estimate for the number of different life forms on earth is 8.7 x 10E6, with another 99.9% that have gone extinct (Benton, et al, 2000). Thus, one can put a theoretical upper boundary at the number of forms of life – past and present (with rounding up) at 10E9. We know that there is extensive duplication among those forms of life in terms of certain highly conserved sequences, so we can add an order of magnitude to account for this. Therefore, rounding up and using maximal estimates, we can provide a value of about $10^10$ that would represent the maximum different forms of life.

P2 relates to the number of chemosynthetic events that could have occurred to generate a primitive proto-organism. We can’t really speak to this being “evolution” as there was no natural selection – there was technically no life yet. Nonetheless, somehow, life began. Let us suppose in this model that amino acids are everywhere in abundance, and (somehow) synthetic mechanisms abound for the creation of peptide bonds. There are no restrictions on concentration of materials, nor shortages of catalytic agents needed to synthesize the amino acid peptide bonds to create proteins.

One million events per second, one million events per microliter, for every microliter in the earth, and for every second in the universe (rounded up).

To clarify:

- The amount of time cannot be higher than the amount of time in the universe.
- The volume provided is set to the entire volume of the earth, not just its surface.
- The density set here is far denser than what one would predict or expect.
- The frequency set here is far faster than what we believe is actually true.

Comment: Please don't re-post a question that was closed. If you wish to do so, edit the original question (to improve its brevity and clarity); this will automatically submit the revision for a Reopen vote.